# PHP XML echoing values contained in a node

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have a XML doc , with 3 article nodes in it , each Article contains :
Title
Image
Link

I need to be able to get the Title/Image/Link values out of the node.

```
$query = $xpath->query('//section/article');

foreach($query as $currentArticle => $artContents):
print_r( $artContents->title);
endforeach
```

;
This doesn't work for me, I can use ->NodeName and nodeValue , but they dont drill down enough , just display 'article' or the whole contents respectively.

To explain more:

My XML is

```
<article>
<title>Title </title>
<link>http:// </link>
<img>image src </img>
</article>
```

and the output I require is :

Title->Title

Link->http://

etc.

Update to explain :

```
foreach($query as $articles):
foreach($articles->childNodes as $childNode) {

    if ($childNode->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {

                  $stored =    $childNode->nodeValue;

                    array_push( $availAds, $stored );           

    }
}
```

endforeach;

is what I currently have thanks to Gordon . This though makes my array look like:

```
//previous values:

      }
  ["1300884672_071.jpg"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["image"]=>
    string(30) "1300884672_071.jpg"
    ["title"]=>
    string(6) "secind title"
    ["link"]=>
    string(10) "grtgrtgrtg"
  }
  ["1300884618_071.jpg"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["image"]=>
    string(30) "1300884618_071.jpg"
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "first title"
    ["link"]=>
    string(10) "http://www.google.com"
  }

//updated values that 
  [0]=>
  string(6) "My Title"
  [1]=>
  string(89) "/1300961550.jpg"
  [2]=>
  string(22) "rtherherhgerg thursada"
  [3]=>
  string(20) "custome 222222222222"
```

I obviously need my array to be consistent, but cannot work out how to do that. Thanks for your patience.

Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what the problem is, but are you looking for

```
foreach($query as $articles):
    foreach($articles->childNodes as $childNode) {
        if ($childNode->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            printf("%s->%s%s", $childNode->nodeName, $childNode->nodeValue, PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
}
```

This will iterate over all the DOMElement nodes that are direct children of the $article nodes returned in the query and print them in this format "nodename->nodevalue" and a newline.

Comment: Hi thanks, this is sort of what I'm trying to achieve, sorry for my poor explanation. This will output the values , but I need to be able to reference each value to place them into an array. So Im trying to get : $title =  $childNode->title $img = $childNode->img etc. which I can then place into the correct array. Thanks. Ive sorted it with a if statement.