# PHP XML XPATH node element iteration and inserting into array

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Ok, so I thought I had this nailed , but sadly not . I have this XML:

```
//XML
this is root--> <story> 
<article>
<title>my title </title>
<img>my image </img>
<link>my link </link
</article>
</story>
```

and then this PHP:

```
//php
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadXML($_SESSION['xml']);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$query = $xpath->query('//section/article');

foreach($query as $article  ):
                $currentTitle = $article->title ;
//edit - mistake in code - $article used for all 
                //$imagearray =  $currentimg->img ;
                //$linkarray =  $currentlink->link ;
                array_push( $availAds,$currentTitle,$imagearray,$linkarray );
        endforeach;
```

So what I'm trying to do is get the 'Title' 'Img' and 'Link' values and insert them into a pre existing array. The array already outputs fine with the previously entered values, but  I then need to be able to output the results of the updated array in this way:

```
    printf(
                    '<input name="ads[%1$s][title]" value="%2$s" style="width:310px;" /><br />',
                    $availAd['image'],
                    $availAd['title']
                );
```

The issue is right now , the foreach returns NULL for $currentTitle , $imagearray and $linkarray

Comment: And what is the problem exactly? Sorry, I must not have read your question well enough.

Comment: @BobFlemming: Retagging to `xpathengines` because this refers to data type of specific XPath engine's result.

Comment: the issue is that $currentimg->img etc. doesnt work. It comes up as NULL for every value in the Foreach

Comment: @BobFlemming: Where is `$currentimg` set?

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake. All of those are "$article" not $currentimg or $currentlink

Comment: @Bob you cannot access the children of a DOMElement by their tagname directly. If you want that, use SimpleXml.

Comment: Could you please provide a self-contained example? I.e. a "complete" xml document and a "runnable" php script shows the error.

Comment: Ive added in more. The XML is very simple , the PHP is part of a large project,  and not easy to make self contained. This part should work as is though, as there are no other variables. Im just putting the XML in and want the array out.

Comment: @gordon, how can I get the parts ? Ive tried item(0) etc.

Comment: @Bob I've already shown you in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418763/php-xml-echoing-values-contained-in-a-node/5419663#5419663. All you have to do is use nodeName for the array keys and nodeValue for the array values and change the printf accordingly.

Comment: @gordon , I really appreciate your help , this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418763/php-xml-echoing-values-contained-in-a-node/5419663#5419663 nearly solves my problem , but doesnt insert into the array correctly, hence I feel the need for proper references. I will post on the other thread where I am. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gordon said: you need [simplexml](http://docs.php.net/simplexml) instead of [domdocument](http://docs.php.net/domdocument)/[domxpath](http://docs.php.net/domxpath) if you want to access child elements like $parent->childelements.
And you probably want to "group" the elements you put into the array for each article element, i.e. instead of
`array_push($arr, $x, $y, $z);`
you probably want
`array_push($arr, array($x, $y, $z));`

self-contained example:

```
<?php
$doc = getDoc();
$arr = foo($doc);
foreach($arr as $ad) {
  echo $ad['title'], " ", $ad['img'], "\n";
}

function foo(SimpleXMLElement $doc) {
  $availAds = array();
  $query = '//section/article';
  foreach( $doc->xpath($query) as $article ) {
    $currentTitle = $article->title ;
  //edit - mistake in code - $article used for all 
                  //$imagearray =  $currentimg->img ;
                  //$linkarray =  $currentlink->link ;
    array_push( $availAds, array(
      'title'=>(string)$article->title, // without the (string) cast 
      'img'=>(string)$article->img,  // you'd store simplexmlelement instances
      'link'=>(string)$article->link  // which _might or might not_ be what you want
    ));
  }
  return $availAds;
}

function getDoc() {
  return new SimpleXMLElement( <<< eoxml
<story>
  <section>
    <article>
      <title>title 1.1</title>
      <img>my image 1.1</img>
      <link>my link 1.1</link>
    </article>
    <article>
      <title>title 1.2</title>
      <img>my image 1.2</img>
      <link>my link 1.2</link>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section>
    <article>
      <title>title 2.1</title>
      <img>my image 2.1</img>
      <link>my link 2.1</link>
    </article>
  </section>
</story>
eoxml
  );
}
```

prints

```
title 1.1 my image 1.1
title 1.2 my image 1.2
title 2.1 my image 2.1
```

Comment: thanks! With a bit of modification this was exactly what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$xml="<story>
<article>
<title>my title</title>
<img>my image</img>
<link>my link</link>
</article>
</story>
";

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$availAds = array();

foreach($xml->article as $article):
    $currentTitle = (string)$article->title ;
    array_push( $availAds, $currentTitle );
endforeach;

print_r($availAds);
```